# Getting href urls using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, java, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to download all csv files from the following url: https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices ,but unfortunately I could not succeed as expected. Here is my attempt:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
market_dataset = soup.findAll("table",{"class":"table table-striped table-condensed table-clean"})
for a in market_dataset.find_all('a', href=True):
    print("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

Can anyone please help me. How can I get all urls' of the csv files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your elements more specific e.g. with `css selectors` and be aware you have to concat the `href` with `baseUrl`:

```
['https://emi.ea.govt.nz'+a['href'] for a in soup.select('td.csv a')]
```

or simply change your code and use `find()` instead of `findAll()` to locate the table, what causes the following attribute error:

> AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

```
market_dataset = soup.find("table",{"class":"table table-striped table-condensed table-clean"})
```

**Note:** *In new code use strict `find_all()` instead of old syntax `findAll()` or a mix of both.*

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

['https://emi.ea.govt.nz'+a['href'] for a in soup.select('td.csv a')]
```

##### Output

```
['https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices/20220318_FinalEnergyPrices_I.csv',
 'https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices/20220317_FinalEnergyPrices_I.csv',
 'https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices/20220316_FinalEnergyPrices.csv',
 'https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices/20220315_FinalEnergyPrices.csv',
 'https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices/20220314_FinalEnergyPrices.csv',
 'https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices/20220313_FinalEnergyPrices.csv',
 'https://emi.ea.govt.nz/Wholesale/Datasets/FinalPricing/EnergyPrices/20220312_FinalEnergyPrices.csv',...]
```